# tocloft parts are misaligned with the chapters

Tags: alignment, tocloft

I'm trying to put the ToC on the cover page using tocloft:

[image]

However, the parts are misaligned with the chapter titles.

How to make the part titles align with the chapter titles ?

**Note:** Sorry, the 2 code files which are about 100 single lines of code each, are not the Minimum Working Example / MWE. Trying to post a MWE seemed so hard that I didn't start doing it. The codes compile fine with the TexLive 2017 and TexLive 2020.

coverpage.tex:

```
\newgeometry{left=0cm,right=0cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.2cm}
\newcommand{\bolumfont}{\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\hfill\color{olive}}}
\newenvironment{MainTOC}{\partfont}{}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
{\fontsize{60pt}{10pt}\selectfont\color{black!60}Altai Mountains\\In A Nutshell}
\\
\color{black!60}\rule[0pt]{365pt}{0.5mm}
\\
\mbox{\Termes \large\color{black!60}Jonikrevoc Moskowic}

\addvspace{5pt} 

\begin{minipage}[]{1.0\textwidth}
% \includegraphics[width=597pt]{img/altai_kutscherla_see}% You can get this image at wikipedia if you wish
\includegraphics[width=597pt]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\addvspace{0pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{MainTOC}
\begin{minipage}[]{0.96\textwidth}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[T]{0.58\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\footnotesize\Alph{part}} % Make parts A B C...
\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}
\setlength{\columnsep}{-8pt}
\cftsetpnumwidth{1em}
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{0.1cm}
\renewcommand\contentsname{}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{5pt}
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip 15pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip 15pt}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % remove dots
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\,\footnotesize/} % Page Numbers next to Titles 
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\,\footnotesize/\:}
\renewcommand\cftpartpagefont{\color{olive}\footnotesize\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\cftpnumalign}{l}
\renewcommand{\cftpartnumwidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
% Redefine the \chapter* header macro to remove vertical space
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \footnotesize % normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \footnotesize \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{spacing}{0.48} % Increase spacings
\newdimen\origiwspc%
\setlength\cftparskip{1pt} % make it 2pt to ease off the line spacings 
\setlength\cftbeforechapskip{-2pt}
% https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7701
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{Q }
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{:}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}

\footnotesize
\tableofcontents
\end{spacing}
\endgroup
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.01\linewidth}%
\fbox{%
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[T]{0.34\textwidth}%
\centering
\fontsize{9}{9}
\setlength{\LTleft}{1pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{l}
% \lipsum[100] % Need to add line endings so lipsum is no use
Phasellus eu quam vitae turpis\\
Duis feugiat felis ut enim\\
Quisque scelerisque dapibus\\
sem id porttitor sodales\\
nec blandit nisl mauris at pede\\
Excepteur sint occaecat cupid\\
eprehenderit in voluptate\\
officia deserunt mollit anim\\
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{minipage}%
\end{MainTOC}
\end{center}

\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
```

main.tex:

```
%! lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt,oneside,]{extbook}
\usepackage[left=1.7cm,right=1.7cm,top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX,Common}}
\newfontfamily{\Termes}{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\PassOptionsToPackage{export}{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames,cmyk,rgb}{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\newcommand{\partfont}{\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\colorlet{red!80!black}{olive}}}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=red!80!black,
  urlcolor=green!50!black,
  hyperfootnotes=false,
  hypertexnames,
  bookmarks=true}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{xparse}
 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % centerdot için de gerekli
 
\setlength{\parindent}{12pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
 
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating minipage widths

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\DeclareListParser{\MyListParser}{|} % $\bullet$
 
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{paracol}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{graphicx}       % for titlepage logo
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}     % number chapters
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}    % list chapters, sections, subsections, etc
\makeindex

\newcommand{\ssection}[1]{%
  \section[#1]{#1}} % \scshape
\newcommand{\ssubsection}[1]{%
  \subsection[#1]{\raggedright\normalfont\itshape #1}}

\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\filright \Huge\thechapter} % \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}
  {1ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\filright}
  [\vspace{1ex}] % \titlerule

\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% To prevent empty page after PART 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@endpart{\vfil
              \if@twoside
                \null
                \thispagestyle{empty}%
                \newpage
              \fi
              \if@tempswa
                \twocolumn
              \fi}
\makeatother

\newcounter{descriptcount}
\renewcommand*\thedescriptcount{\arabic{descriptcount}}
 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{1mm}
\makeatother
 
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{-2.55em}
\makeatother

\usepackage[]{tocloft}

% begindok
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} % I, II, III, IV, V, ...
\include{coverpage}
\pagenumbering{roman} % I, II, III, IV, V, ...
\Termes
\lipsum[500]

\subsection{Foreword}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
\lipsum[20]

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\part{Intro}

\Termes
\chapter{Etymology and names}
\lipsum[20]

\chapter{Geography}
\lipsum[20]

\chapter{Fauna}
\lipsum[20]

\chapter{History}
\lipsum[20]

\chapter{World heritage site}
\lipsum[20]

\chapter{Geology}
\lipsum[20]

\chapter{Seismic Activity}
\lipsum[20]

\chapter{Visiting Mt. Altai}
\lipsum[20]

\part{Packing up the baggage}

\chapter{Here We Go}
\lipsum[20]

\part{Oasis}

\chapter{Sip of wine}
\lipsum[20]

\part{What Else}

\chapter{This isn't last}
\lipsum[20]

\chapter{Any questions?}
\lipsum[20]

\part{Finally...}

\chapter{Licensing terms}
\lipsum[20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have not provided an MWE. What is the documentclass? How are the two files meant to work together? Your MWE needs to be a single file basically containg a `\part` and a `\chapter` to go into the TOC.

Comment: In the `book` class parts and chapters are aligned in the TOC. What have you done?

Comment: Partly unrelated but poissbly relevant: you have a redefinition of `\thepart` which isn't doing anything because it's inside an environment in which there are no `\part` commands. Did you want the parts to have letters rather than Roman numerals?  @PeterWilson I agree that a true MWE would be better, but the document class, etc., is specified in the second code block, and together they do compile.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to the second code block. Dementia is approaching faster than I expected.

Comment: I guess the problem comes from the different format of the `\contentsline` commands in the toc: for Part they have the form `\contentsline {part}{I\hspace {1em}Intro}{2}{part.1}`, putting a constant space between the number and title, but for chapters they use `\numberline` so the titles are all aligned with one another with a constant width allotted to the numbers, which makes them hard to treat alike whatever the settings. Without using a different document class or making big changes elsewhere, it's not obvious to me how to solve that, but someone else might know.

Comment: @PeterWilson 200+ SLOC in 2 files will inevitably cause confusion. Sorry for that. I initially wrote the 2 files separately; one being the cover `coverpage.tex`, the other being the book `main.tex` If I combined them into one single file I reckoned it would be just more difficult to follow the code.

Comment: @frabjous Where is the `\contentsline` to be found in my code? My code doesn't use that command. Btw, I cannot easily use a document class other than `extbook` because `extbook` is the only class which allows (or makes it easy) to use 14pt font, for the whole document.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen It's not in your code, but the code that gets auto-generated during compilation by `\chapter` and `\part` commands and placed in a separate file, probably called `main.toc` in this case.

Comment: Actually that gives me an idea. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the problem seems to be the different way that `\chapter` and `\part` insert `\addcontentsline` into the `.toc` file. `\chapter` uses the `\numberline` command, which can be tweaked by `tocloft` options, but `\part` just puts a constant space between the part number and part title.

The easiest way I can think of fixing this is to redefine the command `\@part` (called by `\part`) so that it also uses `\numberline` when inserting the `\contentsline` for Parts.

Put this right before `\begin{document}` in `main.tex`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname~\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\makeatother
```

Some other changes will be necessary. You need the space dedicated to part numbers to be the same as the space dedicated to chapter numbers. So change the line:

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartnumwidth}{0pt}
```

found in `coverpage.tex` to this:

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartnumwidth}{\cftchapnumwidth}
```

Right now you also have:

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{Q }
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{:}
```

I don't know what the "Q" there is supposed to mean, but with these changes, it'll introduce a "Q" before part numbers, and a colon afterwards, which I'm not sure you want.

Since the chapter numbers are bold, maybe you want the part numbers bold too? Then maybe you want this instead:

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{:}
```

(Or remove the second line for no punctuation there.)

Finally if you want the Part title bold as well, you'll have to have to add that to `\cftpartfont` (you actually already have two different definitions of this elsewhere; I'm tweaking one of them, but you can change as needed):

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\colorlet{red!80!black}{olive}}
```

The result is this:

[image: table of contents results]

You didn't ask about this in your question, but you have a line that redefines `\thepart` to use letters. However, because that redefinition occurs *inside* some limited environments (a center environment, the MainTOC environment, some minipages, etc.), it is not being applied globally, and thus is not active when the `\part` commands are used. So if you do indeed want letters rather than Roman numerals for parts, you might put something like  `\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}` in main.tex instead, say right before `\begin{document}` again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked it out instantly. Yep, my code has numerous peculiar lines. They are because of my trying to make the parts align with the chapters, for instance the "Q" in `renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{Q }` was a dummy text in order to find out what goes before the part title.

Answer (score 1):

To align both chapters and parts (no changes to coverpage.tex)

(1) Define the width of the chapter number width (after `\usepackage{tocloft}`

`\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{2.0em}`

(2) Insert the part number in a box of the same width

```
 \makeatletter
 \def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\parbox{2em}{\thepart}#1}% changed <<<<<<<<
    \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
        \interlinepenalty \@M
        \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
        \huge\bfseries \partname~\thepart
        \par
        \vskip 20\p@
        \fi
        \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart} 
\makeatother
```

[image: a]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works it out quite nice. I'm so glad to have more than one answer to my question. Because the other answer came out 2 minutes before yours I've selected it as accepted.